# How to use one encoder for multi stream out put

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming

I want to make 2 stream from one input and use one HW encoder :

```
$ffmpeg -f v4l2 -s 1440x576 -i /dev/video1  -vcodec cedrus264 -filter:v 'crop=720:576:0:0' -f mpegts udp://192.168.1.120:1234 -vcodec cedrus264 -filter:v 'crop=720:576:720:0' -f mpegts udp://192.168.1.120:1235

  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.82.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (cedrus264), nv12, 736x576, q=2-31, 64 kb/s, 9 fps, 90k tbn, 9 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.106.101 cedrus264
[cedrus264 @ 0x1b65fc0] VE Open error.
Error initializing output stream 1:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #1:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

how to solve this problem? can i use one HW encoder for 2 out put after crop 1 input?

Answer (score 1):

When you use a filter, you are essentially decoding the video first, working on raw pixels, then forwarding the pixels to an encoder before the video stream can be output.

So, the order is:

```
Input --> Demux --> Decode --> Filter --> Encode --> Mux --> Output
```

This means that you cannot use two different filters and use only one encoder. You'd have to do:

```
Input --> Demux --> Decode
                         \__ Filter 1 --> Encode --> Mux --> Output
                          |_ Filter 2 --> Encode --> Mux --> Output
```